# Don't reward after canceling the ad

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

everything works fine. downloading and displaying ads. after showing one gives 1 life. what I want is to not give a prize after canceling the ad. is also annoyed when you leave the ad. how can I make sure that the ad is not killed when it is closed? how can I do it ? is there a function that checks that the ad is fully tracked? or is there a function that checks that the ad is closed? and I can determine the duration of the ads. thank you for your interest

`

```
    // Get singleton reward based video ad reference.
    this.rewardBasedVideo = RewardBasedVideoAd.Instance;

    // RewardBasedVideoAd is a singleton, so handlers should only be registered once.
    this.rewardBasedVideo.OnAdLoaded += this.HandleRewardBasedVideoLoaded;
    this.rewardBasedVideo.OnAdFailedToLoad += this.HandleRewardBasedVideoFailedToLoad;
    this.rewardBasedVideo.OnAdOpening += this.HandleRewardBasedVideoOpened;
    this.rewardBasedVideo.OnAdStarted += this.HandleRewardBasedVideoStarted;
    this.rewardBasedVideo.OnAdRewarded += this.HandleRewardBasedVideoRewarded;
    this.rewardBasedVideo.OnAdClosed += this.HandleRewardBasedVideoClosed;
    this.rewardBasedVideo.OnAdLeavingApplication += this.HandleRewardBasedVideoLeftApplication;
}
public void Update()
{
    // Calculate simple moving average for time to render screen. 0.1 factor used as smoothing
    // value.
    this.deltaTime += (Time.deltaTime - this.deltaTime) * 0.1f;
}

// Returns an ad request with custom ad targeting.
private AdRequest CreateAdRequest()
{
    return new AdRequest.Builder()
        .AddTestDevice(AdRequest.TestDeviceSimulator)
        .AddTestDevice("0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF")
        .AddKeyword("game")
        .SetGender(Gender.Male)
        .SetBirthday(new DateTime(1985, 1, 1))
        .TagForChildDirectedTreatment(false)
        .AddExtra("color_bg", "9B30FF")
        .Build();
}    
private void RequestRewardBasedVideo()

private void ShowRewardBasedVideo()
{
    if (this.rewardBasedVideo.IsLoaded())
    {
        this.rewardBasedVideo.Show();
    }
    else
    {
        MonoBehaviour.print("Reward based video ad is not ready yet");
    }
}`
```

NOTE : cut some small parts because it does not publish the code. it would be enough if you tell me the meaning of not giving a prize only in the cancellation of advertisement.

Comment: This is too broad to answer, but look for a `succeed` event or something like that. if the ad did not succeed, then it is a cancel or failure or abandoning the game etc.

Answer (score 3):

You subscribe to the `OnAdRewarded`-event in your code:

```
 this.rewardBasedVideo.OnAdRewarded += this.HandleRewardBasedVideoRewarded;
```

Your `this.HandleRewardBasedVideoRewarded`-method will be called when the user has completed watching the video.

You can use `OnAdClosed` to see if the ad was closed.

Check out all the events here

> https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/rewarded-video

Comment: I could not use the onAdClosed function properly. I checked the transmission you sent but I could not. Could you demonstrate the use of the onAdClosed function? how do I add the code to where? Thank you for your interest.